# If by selling short assets, you get extra capital for your longs, can you actually be dollar neutral?

Tags: short-selling, longshort

I have a strategy where I short index ETF worth 80% of my portfolio, it shows up in leverage because I've borrowed the asset to short, but now I have 1.8 times the initial capital because of short selling, and that capital is used for rest of portfolio which is long-only

So now I'm holding 180long-80short. How does one actually becomes Dollar neutral?

It may sound like a silly question, but it is confusing me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: you need to borrow 100 to fund your long position rather than pay in cash

Comment: Don't buy 180 of longs, just buy 80 and you will have zero net exposure (80-80=0) and 160 of gross exposure (80+|-80|=160).Which will be well within Prime Broker limits on leverage. You will have excess cash, which is fine, and in fact a good idea. You don't want to be at max leverage obviously, but have some slack.

Comment: When you sell securities you do not get "extra capital" but extra cash. The capital comes from your investors initially and only changes because of your net profits over time.

Answer (score 2):

You should have bought your (long) stocks with the proceeds of the ETF sell.